# How to maintain MongoDB session throughout out application in goLang as global variable

Tags: mongodb, go

I am a beginner in GoLang. I want to maintain a MongoDB session throughout the application. I already have seen answers like binding DB session in martini framework or assigning it to a goLang structs. But I want a straight forward method.

Comment: Store it in a package level variable.  That's easiest for a beginner.

Comment: Could you @MellowMarmot  explain in detail?, because i am totally new to goLang. Could you tell me the flow

Comment: Create the session in main() or some other function before starting the HTTP server. Assign the value to a package level variable. Use it as needed.

Comment: @RaviTejaBathula If a global variable needs explanation, you shouldn't be using MongoDB as of yet. You need to go through the language basics, e.g. [A tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) and the [Language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec).

Comment: @icza Yes I do, Just i thought making a project is a best way to learn. I am making a project and learning as well. Anyhow  thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you've already got the `mgo` driver:

`go get gopkg.in/mgo.v2`

In your code you can set a global variable outside your `main` function like:

`var mgoSession *mgo.Session`

Then either in an `init` function or right in your `main` function you start up your session:

```
session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://localhost")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
mgoSession = session
```

Then you can clone the session as needed in the different functions in your program:

```
session := mgoSession.Clone()
defer session.Close()
c := session.DB("databasename").C("collectionname")
```

Comment: Thank you @nosequeldeebee , instead of simply down voting, you took patience to write this. I got it